# Access denied SUPER privilege(s) error in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

MysqlError: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

My query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_one ORDER BY field_id SEPARATOR '-') AS field_ans FROM table_name';
```

- field_one [am storing upto 450 characters].
- Using GROUP_CONCAT, am trying to get multiple row values in a single column.

Note: Don't want to Run 'SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4096' in phpmyadmin. I want the change in PHP file.

am using group_concat in my query, so i increased group_concat_max_len value from 
'default:1024 to 4096' for that query alone.

```
$sql = "SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4096";
```

How to get rid of the error, am getting the error in my log file??

Comment: Exactly what the error is saying, you need `SUPER` privilege.

Comment: See am trying to increase the group_concat_max_value instead of changing .ini file. for the 'SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4096' is ask me some privilege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to change `group_concat_max_len` for the whole database (ie not just your query/session) and that requires database administrator privileges.

If you just want to change it for your session, instead use;

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=15000;
```

...which will change it for your session only and does not require any elevated privileges.